# scala specs2 - how to match a list of matchers or criterias?

Tags: scala, unit-testing, matcher, specs2

The pain:

```
val someString = "how are you today?"
val expectedWordsInStringList = List("how", "you")
```

How can i match that the string contains all the expected words ?

```
  //would of liked to have: (there is no method containAllElements)
  someString must containAllElements(expectedWordsInStringList)
```

Ended up writing this test (and not happy about the result)

```
class HowToMatchListOfMatcher extends Specification {
  "HowToMatchListOfMatcher" should {
    "not use reduce to match on list of matchers" in {

      val testString = "some string with 1 and 2"

      val containList:List[String] = List("1", "2")
      val matcherList:List[Matcher[String]] = List(contain("1"), contain("2"))

      def matchAll(matcherList: List[Matcher[String]]) = matcherList.reduce((m1,m2)=> m1 and m2)

      //how can i match this without reduce ? or with using the containList
      testString must matchAll(matcherList)

    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can split the string on spaces then use `contain(allOf(...))`

```
val someString = "how are you today?".split(" ").toSeq
someString must contain(allOf("how", "you"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could define a custom string matcher. How about

```
import org.specs2.mutable._
import org.specs2.matcher.{Expectable, Matcher}

class HowToMatchListOfMatcher extends Specification {

  import CustomMatchers._

  "HowToMatchListOfMatcher" should {
    "not use reduce to match on list of matchers" in {

      val testString = "some string with 1 and 2"

      testString must containAllSubstringsIn(List("1", "2", "bar"))

    }
  }
}

object CustomMatchers {
  def containAllSubstringsIn(expectedSubstrings: Seq[String]) = new Matcher[String] {
    def apply[S <: String](expectable: Expectable[S]) = {
      result(expectedSubstrings.forall(expectable.value.contains(_)),
        expectable.description + " contains all substrings in " + expectedSubstrings,
        expectable.description + " doesn't contain all substrings in " + expectedSubstrings + "\nMissing substrings: " + expectedSubstrings.filterNot(expectable.value.contains(_)), expectable)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: i would have expected specs2 has a out of the box matcher for list of items

Comment: @Nimrod007 There is `containAllOf[T](seq: Seq[T])` in the trait `org.specs2.matcher.TraversableBaseMatchers`. However, I am not sure if this is of any use as there are explicit `StringBaseMatchers` (such as the `contains` method you are using) and I cant find something like `containAllOf` there.